# Jquery adding display: none; to li

Tags: jquery, slider

I've altered a Jquery UI set up to scroll through some featured posts

its works fine here (still have to style the insides)
http://nottingham.subverb.net/featured-content-slider/index.php

however, when I take that script and place it into my homepage, the menu on the right doesn't display...and it's because each list item has 'display: none;' added inline and I have no idea why

http://nottingham.subverb.net

I have tried disabling all the other scripts I have on the page and the only thing that makes it come back is removing jquery itself - however obviously this stops the slider working

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a typo:

```
<ul class="featured_list"><li class="featured_list_item" display: block" id="nav-fragment-1">
```

should probably be

```
<ul class="featured_list"><li class="featured_list_item" id="nav-fragment-1">
```

Comment: And you appear to have written a rather ambiguous question. It's good practice to include a code sample of the problem you are having, as "'display: none; added inline'" is not a sufficient explanation of your problem. "Inline" has a specific meaning in this context (css embedded in html), referring to the use of the style= attribute. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp